# How can I use 7400-series chips to translate the following 5-bit signals into the desired 8-bit signals?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit

How can I turn the following 5-bit signals into the desired 8-bit signals? Using only 7400-series chips.

```
11111 into 00001111,
01111 into 00000011,
00111 into 00000000,
00011 into 10000011,
00001 into 10001111
```

Comment: What about the 27 other inputs?

Comment: Also, did you notice that you actually only have 3 bits of output?

Comment: ... and only 4 bits of input?

Comment: I can do it with three inverters and two 2-input NAND gates.

Comment: Why the 7400 requirement?

Comment: @jippie The 7400 series chips are used a lot in college entry level Digital Logic courses, my assumption is that this is for a class of some sort.

Comment: @DaveTweed: three two-input XNOR gates (one could be just an inverter). When you count at the gate level that is less than your 5 gates, but at the transistor level your version is probably smaller and faster. (but mine can be had in one chip: 747266).

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82265/how-can-i-turn-a-5-bit-signal-to-an-8-bit-signal because that question is general, whereas this one is about one specific translation. Vote to re-open.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, unless you recognize some obvious pattern (such as the outputs being a shift or inverse of the inputs), you'd write and reduce an expression for each individual output bit, as a function of all input bits.

The classic paper tool for doing these reductions is the [Karnough Map (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

This will typically give you an expression as a sum of products, which is to say an `OR` function following one or more `AND` functions, potentially with inverters in some places - or if you prefer you can use de Morgan's law to convert to its product-of-sums dual, with the gates in the other order.  Each can be implemented by a combination of AND, OR and inverter gates, or NAND and NOR - in fact you can do the whole thing using only NAND chips or only NOR chips.

Some particular functions may be more efficiently implemented with other special devices, for example the `138 decoder.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer sent me in the direction that allowed me to solve my problem.